# Fit the large image into small imageview with as good quality as the original image?

Tags: android, android-imageview

Hello I am working on one good android app where I need to fit the large bitmap into small size `imageview`. I am using `imageview` of size *300dp X 300dp* to display large image *1024 X 780*

How can I make the large image into small with as good quality as the original image ?

Comment: You should make a Thumbnail image of size 300x300 but preserving its aspect ratio. You can draw larger images on a canvas centered with some color filling the rest of the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nikola comment answered to my question. I am writing this in the answer so that it would good for future readers

> You should make a Thumbnail image of size 300x300 but preserving its aspect ratio. You can draw larger images on a canvas centered with some color filling the rest of the space.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `im.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY)`

Comment: **Don't use this for that.** `FIT_XY` does *not* maintain the aspect ratio, and will stretch your image. `FIT_CENTER` would be more appropriate.